# Create link in PDF to open in new window/tab

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have a PDF document embedded in a web page with an object tag.  Is it possible to create a link inside the PDF document that opens in a new tab/window?

I have tried:

```
app.launchURL("www.google.com", true);
```

but it does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it must be built in PDF file.

you can do it like following the links below:

-[Creating hyperlinks in acrobat](http://blogs.adobe.com/acrolaw/2010/04/creating-hyperlinks-in-adobe-acrobat/)

-[Add Interactive Links](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/add-interactive-links-to-pdf-documents.html)

And if you want to alter the opening of every link, you can do it in jquery style like:

```
$('a[href$=".pdf"]').prop('target', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but the link must be in the PDF, the document itself.
That if you open the .pdf in your computer, the link must work.